# Shift data in excel Sheet to left to remove empty cells and include Header names

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have an Excel sheet like this and want to remove the empty cells between the blocks of data by shifting these block towards Column A, up against the previous block of data. A block of data has the same Header so in Row 1 columns A and B data under the header '1' is one block.
[image: Input Sheet]

For example in Row 2 Columns A - D are empty and Column E contains the first block of data in header '3'. I want to move the data to the start of the row. Then the next block under header '4' moves next to the first block in the same row.

However I also want to put the Header name the data was originally under in the column to the left of the block.
So using Row 2 again as the example;
the first block is under header 3 moved to the start of the row. Since the original headers are to be in the column on the left this will be to column B. In column A enter 3 for the original header for that block.
Then for the next block under header '4' move that up to column E placing a '4' in the column D for the original header for that block.
So the row now has no empty cells from column A across until the last block and each block is preceded by the header name of it's original position.

The result should be like the following;
[image: Resultant Sheet]

I can place header names ( 1,2,3,4..) but I cant place the values

```
from  openpyxl import *
mybook = load_workbook("newtry.xlsx")
myvalue= []
sheet=mybook.active
for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, min_col=1, max_row=5, max_col=6):
        for cell in row:
            myvalue.append(cell.value)


x=1
for i in myvalue:
    x=x+1
    if i == 1:
        for row, entry in enumerate('i', start=1):
            sheet.cell(row=x, column=1, value=1)
    book.save("newtry2.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your assistance. Firstly, the correction made to my question was incorrect.On the contrary, I was attempting to make an adjustment.I solved it like this.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("newrty.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')
with pd.ExcelWriter("news.xlsx", engine='openpyxl') as writer:
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        start_s = index + 1
        if row[0] == 1:
            start = 0
        elif row[0] == 2:
            start = 3
        elif row[0] == 3:
            start = 6
        elif row[0] == 4:
            start = 9
        data_df = pd.DataFrame(row).T
        data_df.to_excel(writer, index=False, startrow=start_s, startcol=start, header=False)
```

I will also apply the same code line to the other headings found in the lines. After ensuring the checks on the headings in the lines, I preferred to manually delete them.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit complex but can be done with Pandas

Use Pandas to shift the cells with values to the left.
Dump the Header for each group into a List before shifting so that data can be inserted after the shift.

```
import pandas as pd


def shift_cols_left(df_row, ncd):
    original_columns = df_row.index.tolist()

    ### Drop NaN cells
    shifted = df_row.dropna()

    cur_row = df_row.name  # Current Row in the DataFrame being compressed
    ### Create a dictionary of the Headers to be added as new columns
    ### This will lists of the original Column Headers for the data. To be inserted into the compressed DataFrame
    for col_count, col in enumerate(shifted):
        section_header = shifted.index[shifted == col].values[0]
        if 'Unnamed' not in str(section_header):  # Use actual Header names only
            cur_col = f"col{col_count}"
            if cur_col in ncd:
                ncd[cur_col] += [section_header]
            else:
                if cur_row > 0:  # Pad the list if needed
                    for x in range(cur_row):
                        if cur_col in ncd:
                            ncd[cur_col] += ['']
                        else:
                            ncd[cur_col] = ['']
                    ncd[cur_col] += [section_header]
                else:
                    ncd[cur_col] = [section_header]

    ### Shift columns with values to the left removing gaps and update column headers
    shifted.index = [original_columns[n] for n in range(shifted.count())]

    return shifted


filepath = 'newtry.xlsx'
sheet = 'Sheet1'

new_col_dict = {}

### Read the original Data from Excel
df = pd.read_excel(filepath, sheet_name=sheet)
print(f"Original DataFrame:\n{df}\n----------------------------------\n")

### Remove empty cells and shift data to the left
df1 = df.apply(shift_cols_left, args=(new_col_dict,), axis=1)
print(f"Left shifted DataFrame\n{df1}\n----------------------------------\n")

### Insert the Header detail into the DataFrame at first row then each 3rd row as necessary
loc = 0
for k, v in new_col_dict.items():
    df1.insert(loc=loc, column=k, value=pd.Series(v))
    loc += 3

### Final DataFrame with shifted data and Header Columns inserted
### Not bothering with renaming Headers as these will be dropped when writing to Excel
print(f"Left shifted DataFrame with header columns included:\n{df1}\n----------------------------------\n")

### Write the resultant DataFrame to Excel
### Drop Index and Header
with pd.ExcelWriter('newtry2.xlsx') as writer: 
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, header=False)
```

**Input Sheet**
The Sheet is a duplication of that shown in the Question. I am assuming the Headers on Row 1 are merged cells.
I.e. A1 & B1, C1 & D1, E1 & F1 and G1 & H1 cells are individually merged.
[image: Sheet to change]

**Output Sheet**
[image: Resultant Sheet]
As is the code sample will create a **new** 'newtry2.xlsx' (**overwriting any existing file with that name in the same directory**).
If required the writer can be changed to write to an existing file without overwriting. Can also have it write to an existing or new sheet at any location.

As shown in the Question Output Image there are no Headers included.
Headers can be changed/updated in the DataFrame and included with the write to Excel, or
Headers can be inserted after the DataFrame is written using the ExcelWriter engine.

Comment: IMO we can do better with `pandas`. What if we start with `df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', header=[0,0])` and then replace the second header level with the positional number of a column inside a block? Then we could unpivot the very first level, group the rows by block names and append to a new sheet the flattened values of groups. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we are limited to the [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) module. So I think it would be better to create a new sheet, filling it row-by-row with converted data using the [Worksheet.append](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.append) method. Its only argument should be an *iterable* object, that is, it can be a generator that sequentially supplies non-empty blocks in the desired format. The blocks boundaries inferred from the first (header) row can be used to split the data along the others.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

file_name = '/path/to/your/file.xlsx'
data_sheet = 'Data sheet title'
blocks_sheet = 'Blocks sheet title'

book = load_workbook(file_name)
data = book[data_sheet]

columns = [cell.value for cell in data[1]]
pos = [position for position, name in enumerate(columns) if name]
pos.append(len(columns))    # include the rightmost boundary
names = [name for name in columns if name]


def shrink(row):
    '''Generate a sequence of non-empty blocks preceded by the corresponding  headers'''
    for name, left, right in zip(names, pos[:-1], pos[1:]):
        if any(row[left:right]):
            yield name
            yield from row[left:right]

            
if blocks_sheet in book.sheetnames:
    del book[blocks_sheet]
blocks = book.create_sheet(blocks_sheet)
for row in data.iter_rows(2, values_only=True):
    blocks.append(shrink(row))

book.save(file_name)
```